# Undergraduate Linear Algebra Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are matrices such that $I - AB$ is invertible, then the inverse of $I - BA$  is given by the formula

$(I - BA)^{-1} = I + B(I - AB)^{-1}A$

People, please help!

Comment: please, show us what are your thoughts about this problem.

Comment: On a side note, there is a mock proof of this identity using power series. Once you see it, you can't forget about it!

Comment: Well, to keep it simple... verify your claim. Multiply the RHS by $(I-BA)$ and show it equals $I$ via some simple manipulations

Answer (score 1):

Let's compute

$$\begin{align}(I-BA)(I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A)&=I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A-BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A-BA\\&=I+(B-BAB)(I-AB)^{-1}A-BA\\&=I+B(I-AB)(I-AB)^{-1}A-BA\\&=I+BA-BA\\&=I\end{align}$$

And we have proven $(I-BA)^{-1}=I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A$

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to compute elements of $I - BA$. I'm not used to work with matrices like with numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Let us multiply both sides of the  equality by (I - BA) from the right:
$$ I  = [ I + B(I - AB)^{-1}A](I - BA)  $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow I  =  I - BA + B(I - AB)^{-1} A(I - BA) $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow BA = B(I - AB)^{-1} A(I - BA) $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow A = (I - AB)^{-1} A(I - BA)  $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow  (I - AB)A = A(I - BA)$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow  A - ABA = A - ABA $$

This should make it clear how to prove it.